# matplotlib FuncFormatter string formatting carries into figure coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting

The following code uses matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter to format the tick labels. It works fine on the plot but causes the raw string format to mess with the coordinates in the bottom right of the figure.
How can I continue to use my custom formatting while not causing the raw formatting to make it into the coordinates on the bottom right of the figure? I have delved into the ticker and scale functions of matplotlib to no avail, but perhaps I am missing something that matplotlib does to keep the coordinates from being formatted like the ticks.

The expected output is something more in line with the default scientific notation like 6.68548e+07 or similar.

Thanks for your help :)

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def customFormatter(value, _):
    if abs(value) > 1000:
        if value < 0:
            sign = '-'
            value *= -1
        else:
            sign = ''
        exponent = int(np.floor(np.log10(value)))
        multiplier = value / (10 ** exponent)
        if multiplier % 1 < 0.0000001:
            multiplier = int(multiplier)
        if multiplier == 1:
            label = str((r'$%s%s^{%d}$') % (sign, 10, exponent))
        else:
            label = str((r'$%s%g\times%s^{%d}$') % (sign, multiplier, 10, exponent))
    else:
        label = str('{0:g}'.format(value))
    return label

X = np.linspace(0, 10 ** 8, 1000)
Y = np.exp(-10 ** -7 * X) * np.sin(10 ** -6 * X)
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(customFormatter))
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: bad_formatting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to modify the format of the coordinates displayed in the bottom right is to set the [`Axes.format_coord`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_coord.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_coord). I don't know why changing the `xaxis.major_formatter` has affected that.

In your case, setting it to something like this seems to work fine.

```
plt.gca().format_coord = lambda x, y:  "x={:g}, y={:g}".format(x, y)
```

[image]